# Singleton through object literal versus module pattern, code organization pros&cons

Tags: javascript

Which one do you prefer and what are pros & cons one over another ?.
Personally i found singleton hard to read and maintain, a lot of context changes(*this*), always ends with caching right context through `var self = this` (or some proxy like `$.proxy`) + i will always have one global variable(singleton), while in second approach i can avoid creating global variable if module doesn't need to expose any API.

Simple example: 
(User click on "add to cart", some ajax get triggered and on success html(notification) is created) 
**Html**

```
<div class="cart">
    <a href="#" data-product-id="200"> Add to cart </a>
</div>
```

**Module pattern**
Not truly module pattern by definition, because i'm not returning anything from it, click handler can access outer scope via closure.

```
;(function(window, $, undefined) {

    function constructHtml(data) {...}

    function addToCart(product_id, quantity) {
        ...

        $.ajax({
            ...
            success: function(data) { constructHtml(data); }
        });
    }


    $(function() {
        var $addBtn = $('div.cart a');
        var productId = $addBtn.data('product-id');

        $addBtn.click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            addToCart(productId);
        });
    });

})(this, jQuery);
```

**Singleton - Object literal(same example)**

```
var Cart = {
    settings: {
        $addBtn: $('div.cart a'),
        productId: $('div.cart a').data('product-id') 
    },
    init: function() {
        this.bindUiActions();
    },
    bindUiActions: function() {
        var self = this;

        this.settings.$addBtn.click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            self.addToCart(self.settings.productId);
        });
    },
    addToCart: function(product_id, quantity) {
        ...
        var self = this;

        $.ajax({
            ...
            success: function(data) {
                self.constructHtml(data);
            }
        });
    },
    constructHtml: function(data) {...}
};

Cart.init();
```

Comment: The module pattern can also implement singletons, and you don't necessarily need a variable for an object literal: `({ … }).init();`

Comment: *Which one do you prefer* - it doesn't matter, you can use (and even combine) both at need. *what are pros & cons one over another?* - you've named them already in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Singleton vs. Module Pattern can be a legitimate question, with the example you gave, this question should be reworded as Singleton vs [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), as it's not the module pattern per se, but rather the IIFE that the module pattern is wrapped in that is keeping cruft out of your `Cart` singleton. And even then, it's not a vs. kind of question -- both IIFE and Singleton can be used together. The purpose of the IIFE is just to keep stuff out of global scope.

So ..., you can package your singleton Code into an IIFE as follows

```
;(function(){
  var Cart = {
    settings: {
      // Your code ...
  };

  Cart.init();
})();
```

In this case, you're writing your code as a Singleton but wrapping it in an IIFE, and there is no usage of global scope. The IIFE is completely independent of how you choose to write and organize your code. You would need a different example for a Singleton vs. Module Pattern question.

Answer (score 0):

**IIFE (immediately invoked function expression):**

```
(function() {
    console.log('run this in your browser console')
})()
```

**Module pattern:**

```
var module = (function () {
    var privateScopeVar = 1 // scope of the IIF  

    // the 'this' context in this scope is the global object (e.g. window)

    // returns literal object who's method's scopes are lexically bound 
    // to the IIF scope
    return {
      publicMethod: () => privateScopeVar // publicMethod scope can access IIF scope 
    }
})()
```

**Singleton Literal + Singleton Literal that cannot be overwritten if included/imported more than once in EcmaScrip5:**

```
var singleInstance = { firstName: 'Greg' }
var singleInstance = singleInstance || { firstName: 'Greg' }
```

**Singleton Literal that cannot be overwritten or initialized more than once in EcmaScrip6:**

```
const singleInstance = { 
    firstName: 'Greg', 
    called: false, 
    init: () => { 
        if (!this.called) {
            console.log('only once')
            this.called = true
        }
    } 
}

// of course singleInstance.called = false; singleInstance.init() is always possible
```

**Singleton inside IIF (provides private state)**

```
const singleton = (function () {
    // IIF private scope ensures there is a single instance ever
    var storedInstance

    // Also some private state for the singleton instance as well
    const firstName = 'Greg'


    // literal object that holds constructor function
    const Singleton = {
        getInstance: () => {
            if (!storedInstance) {
                storedInstance= {
                    getName: () => firstName
                }
            }
            return storedInstance
        }
    }

    return Singleton
})()
```